# Update NodeJs -> Error when i add Android

Tags: android, node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

***Hello
I become an new Workspace in my Company. So that is install a new nodejs Version. 12.4.0
When i clone my Ionic Project and while add the Platform Android i become always this error.***

```
[cordova-res] Something went wrong installing the “sharp” module
[cordova-res]
[cordova-res] The module ‘\?\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova-res\node_modules\sharp\build\Release\sharp.node’
[cordova-res] was compiled against a different Node.js version using
[cordova-res] NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js requires
[cordova-res] NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
[cordova-res] the module (for instance, using npm rebuild or npm install).
[cordova-res]
[cordova-res] - Ensure the version of Node.js used at install time matches that used at runtime
[cordova-res] - Consult the installation documentation at https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/install/
[cordova-res] - Search for this error at https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues
[cordova-res]
```

Can anybode help me? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to update Sharp first.

so type in your console

```
npm remove sharp
```

and once it's deleted

```
npm install sharp
```